# Rails Console - Group By count and display referenced column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have 2 models, `Bug (id, status_id)` and `Status(id, desc)`

How can I get the output like 
`bug_status_desc`, `bug_count`

the output should be

```
{NEW=>1, REOPEN=>2}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
Bug.group(:status).count
```

Result is

```
(0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, status_id AS status_id FROM `bugs` GROUP BY `bugs`.`status_id`  ORDER BY created_at DESC
Status Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` WHERE `statuses`.`id` IN (1, 3)
=> 
{#<Status:0x007fb210991370 id: 1, desc: "NEW">=>1,
#<Status:0x007fb210991118 id: 3, desc: "REOPEN">=>2}
```

Comment: Do you mean result should be `{"NEW"=>1, "REOPEN"=>2}` (strings, not constants) ?

Comment: Yes, should be string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Bug.joins(:status).group('statuses.desc').count
```

(assuming you have corresponding relations in models)

Comment: Thanks I get the result as expected, but now since I have a default scope, the sql results ina failure as the default scope is not in the result set, any thoughts how I could get this as well working without changing the default scope

Comment: You can use `unscoped` to disable `default_scope` for particular query